Is it possible to put an instant onto the stack without casting it?
My opponent has cast Archon of Valor's Reach, naming Instant as the spell type that can't be cast by players.
Is it still possible to get Instants onto the stack somehow, from the hand or other zones, after it is put onto the battlefield?

Note, that the opponent doesn't name instant when they cast Archon.  They name instant after Archon enters the battlefield.  So, if you are concerned they "might" pick instant, you do have a window of opportunity to respond.

Two ways of placing instants on the stack: Through casting and through copying. Also, in theory, something could become an instant after being placed on the stack.

tl;dr: no.
To state the obvious answer first: the most obvious way is to remove the Archon from play, most likely either with a sorcery, an activated ability or a triggered ability. Other possibilities exist such as taunting the Archon into combat or fighting it.
If you can't do that, the next most likely is to remove its ability, for example with Humility or Dress Down.
Beyond that and to answer the question as written, the most usual way to get a spell onto the stack without casting it is for it to be a copy of a spell. However, with the exception of epic spells which are not useful in this scenario, I'm not sure there's a way to trigger the copy effect without casting the spell in the first place.
